# Adding Security Using Chef Cookbook Pipeline

Tags: security, chef-infra

A cookbook is the fundamental unit of configuration and policy distribution. A cookbook defines a scenario and contains everything that is required to support that scenario. 
- Can we use a fixed template in all the cookbooks which developed by all teams to add some security features to all systems?
- What would be some example for that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your question is very vague but as Chef is, at heart, a programming framework, the is probably "yes, go write the code to do that thing you said". Security is not a single thing that can be added or subtracted to, and in general trying to share a single cookbook between multiple teams (in terms of ownership, not use) is probably going to be difficult in the same way as building any cross-team tool or library is. But no technical reason you can't so good luck :)